# Thunderbird: Can I go to message by number

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I have configured Thunderbird to display the optional column "Order Received" in my inbox, and to sort my inbox by this field.  I find it very convenient for browsing my large inbox, but jumping to a message with a particular number is rather cumbersome.  Is there any way to assign a keboard shortcut, either in Thunderbird itself or by using some plug-in?

For example, let's say I have written myself a note pointing to message 214640; currently the only way I can navigate to it is by scrolling the inbox pane with the mouse.  The scrollbar is a rather blunt tool (in a large inbox, a small movement will scroll by several hundred messages) and I will typically already have the message number on the clipboard, so something like <kbd>control+g</kbd> <kbd>shift+insert</kbd> <kbd>ret</kbd> would seem like an easy and natural way to get there, but I cannot find a built-in function for anything like this (and my attempts at Googling inevitably find oodles of resources which explain basic to intermediate keyboard navigation, but nothing about this particular use case).

I observe that when I view the source of a message, the window's title contains a (pseudo?) URL like `Source of imap://tripleee@example.com:993/fetch%3EUID%3E/INBOX%3E123456` so it seems that there is an internal representation for addressing messages which I would like to have access to from the GUI somehow.

For what it's worth, I'm on Xubuntu 12.04, Thunderbird 17.0.8.

Comment: Have you considered tagging the message?

Comment: I routinely tag and/or star messages and/or open them in new tabs and/or separate windows but that doesn't particularly help solve the scenario "call K re: message #123456", say, as a calendar entry.

Comment: I suspect you'd need to write a Thunderbird extension, and while I've done a little of that, I don't know how easy it's going to be to hook into the quick filter bar's functionality. It's doable, most likely, but it would be much quicker and less effort to find a way of referring to messages that doesn't require hacking Thunderbird to implement.

Comment: That said, if you do go the extension route, you'd probably do well to start [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/qfb-pivot/); that looks like it should serve as a decent worked example of how to hook the quick filter bar in extension code.